# In Azure DevOps, how do I create a query for those items nearing their target date?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm wondering if there's a way to create a query for items that are nearing the target date (5 days from the target day). I want to use this to monitor those items so that I could remind the team on their due dates.

Comment: What is the target date? a field in the work item?

Comment: Yes, it's a date field of a work item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there's a way to create a query for items that are nearing the target date (5 days from the target day).

You can use `>=` and `+5` to query work items which are 5 days from the date. Here is an example:

[image]

You can replace the `@StartOfDay` in the example with anything else you want, such as `@StartOfMonth`, `@CurrentIteration`.

You can also use specific dates. In that case you don't need to use `+5`, just `>=` a specific date.

Click [Query by date or current iteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops) for more detailed information.